# issue in converting a dtype('O')to date format

Tags: python, pandas, date, format

Hi i am having dates (under column name: 'earliest_cr_line') in raw data set, however when I check the dtype on Jupyter it is dtype('O'), I used the following code to convert to date time format in following code:

```
pd.to_datetime(final_3['earliest_cr_line'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

But this code is showing the error as ValueError: time data 'Jan-85' does not match format '%m/%Y' (match)

how do I convert that entire column into date format and then create another column where I see the difference in months between that date and June 30th 2015

Comment: can you provide some part of your data ? something like `df.head(5)` in question

Comment: id
1077501    Jan-85
1077430    Apr-99
1077175    Nov-01
1076863    Feb-96
1075358    Jan-96
Name: earliest_cr_line, dtype: object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all datetime has format `MMM-YY` and `MMM` is first 3 letters of months names use:

```
print (final_3)
        id earliest_cr_line
0  1077501           Jan-85
1  1077430           Apr-99
2  1077175           Nov-01
3  1076863           Feb-96
4  1075358           Jan-96

final_3['earliest_cr_line'] = pd.to_datetime(final_3['earliest_cr_line'], format='%b-%y')

final_3['diff'] = (pd.to_datetime('2015-06-30') - final_3['earliest_cr_line']).dt.days
print (final_3)
     id earliest_cr_line   diff
0  1077501       1985-01-01  11137
1  1077430       1999-04-01   5934
2  1077175       2001-11-01   4989
3  1076863       1996-02-01   7089
4  1075358       1996-01-01   7120
```

EDIT: You can subtract 100 years by some treshold, here is used `year > 2021`:

```
print (final_3)
        id earliest_cr_line
0  1077501           Jan-63
1  1077430           Apr-99
2  1077175           Nov-01
3  1076863           Feb-96
4  1075358           Jan-96

final_3['earliest_cr_line'] = pd.to_datetime(final_3['earliest_cr_line'], format='%b-%y')

mask = final_3['earliest_cr_line'].dt.year > 2021
h = pd.DateOffset(years=100)
final_3.loc[mask, 'earliest_cr_line'] = final_3['earliest_cr_line'] - h

final_3['diff'] = (pd.to_datetime('2015-06-30') - final_3['earliest_cr_line']).dt.days

print (final_3)
        id earliest_cr_line   diff
0  1077501       1963-01-01  19173
1  1077430       1999-04-01   5934
2  1077175       2001-11-01   4989
3  1076863       1996-02-01   7089
4  1075358       1996-01-01   7120
```

Comment: This is showing a time error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'str'

Comment: @DipojjalSaha - So do yo uassign back by `final_3['earliest_cr_line'] = ` in `final_3['earliest_cr_line'] = pd.to_datetime(final_3['earliest_cr_line'], format='%b-%y')` ?

Comment: yes:
final_3['earliest_cr_line'] = pd.to_datetime(final_3['earliest_cr_line'], format='%b-%y')
final_3['diff'] = (pd.to_datetime('2015-06-30') - final_3['earliest_cr_line']).dt.days

Comment: @DipojjalSaha - Edited answer, for me working very well.

Comment: There seems to be an issue while converting dates for example 01-01-1963 it is reading as 01-01-2063. this is happening to all dates before 1969. Any fix to this?